# CommandLine Parser always parsing bool to true

Tags: c#, command-line

I am using CommandLine Parser package in VS project like here https://commandline.codeplex.com.

But my bool property always pass to true. And here is how I pass my arg:

`app.exe -b false`

But it eventually end as true.

Comment: a [mcve] would be great!

Comment: Did you try any of [the other input options](https://commandline.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Input%20Specification&referringTitle=Attributes-Define-Your-Syntax)?